# in PHP how to generate all possible patterns of a string?

Tags: php

I have this code to generate all posibilites of a string

```
  <?PHP       
  for($i=0;$i< 16;$i++){

    echo decbin($i)."<br>";
  }
  ?>
```

this will print

```
0

1

10

11

100

101

110

111

1000

1001

1010
```

what I want is combining this binary data with a string of 4 letters by replacing all the ones with "*"
so when you input the string "help" you will get

```
help

hel*

he*p

he**
```

etc...

I am struggling
any Idea will be appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: You solve these kind of problems best with a pencil and a sheet of paper.

Answer (score 1):

Warning: 100% untested

```
$s='help';
$l = strlen($s)-1;
for($i=0;$i<=$len;$i++){
  $bin=decbin($i);
  $newS = $s;
  foreach(str_split($bin) as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v) {
     $index = $l - $k;
     $newS[$index] = '*';
    }
  }

  echo $newS.'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple recursive algorithm for this problem.

The idea of the algorithm is that you can look at the binary numbers, and see that a `0` means the character will stay the same, and `1` means it will turn into an asterisk. You do that per character, and since you have a 4 character long word, you got `2*2*2*2 = 16` permutations.

The algorithm goes over the characters in the word, and for each character it tries to generate the permutations of it as a normal character and as an asterisk. The result is all the permutations of the word `help` when each character is either as it self, or covered with an asterisk.

```
function asterisk_permutations($str, &$result=array(), $i=0) {
    if ($i >= strlen($str)) {
        $result[] = $str;
        return;
    }

    asterisk_permutations($str, $result, $i+1);
    asterisk_permutations(substr_replace($str, '*', $i, 1), $result, $i+1);
}

asterisk_permutations("help", $result);
var_dump($result);
```

And the output is:

```
array(16) {
  [0]=> string(4) "help"
  [1]=> string(4) "hel*"
  [2]=> string(4) "he*p"
  [3]=> string(4) "he**"
  [4]=> string(4) "h*lp"
  [5]=> string(4) "h*l*"
  [6]=> string(4) "h**p"
  [7]=> string(4) "h***"
  [8]=> string(4) "*elp"
  [9]=> string(4) "*el*"
  [10]=> string(4) "*e*p"
  [11]=> string(4) "*e**"
  [12]=> string(4) "**lp"
  [13]=> string(4) "**l*"
  [14]=> string(4) "***p"
  [15]=> string(4) "****"
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why would someone downvote without an explanation?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it could be that your code will result in a stackoverflow for longer strings, and the website's name is stackoverflow.

Comment: No, you can say that about the maximum recursive function call depth.

Comment: @Tiberiu-IonuțStan: The maximum recursive depth limit is NOT a PHP core feature. Running out of memory is another story, and any script might be a victim of that.

Answer (score 0):

an easy approach would be:

1. pad bincode so 0 => 0000
2. loop bincode, and replace word[n] with * if bincode[n] = 0.